# How to pass variables between modules

Tags: python

**I tired to print the winner with lower number of guesses, how to use count and counter variable from other modules in main.py. I tried using import, but it did not work, help!**

main.py

```
from random import randint

from player_1 import player_1
from player_2 import player_2




def turn():
    global valid
    global val
    rand = randint(1, 2)
    player_turn = int(input("enter number 1 or 2"))
    if rand == player_turn:
        print("player 1 won the toss")
        valid = True

    else:
        print("player 2 won the toss")
        val = True
```

def play_game():

```
valid = True
val = True
while valid:

    player_1()
    break
while val:
    player_2()
    break

if counter > count:
    print("player 1 won")
else:
    print("player 2 won")
```

turn()
play_game()

player_1.py (how to use counter from here to main)

```
from random import randint
def player_1():


    rand_num = randint(1,100) # we generating a random int 1, 100

    counter = 0
    while True:
        guess_num = int(input('Guess a number b/w 1 to 100'))
        counter += 1
        if rand_num > guess_num:
            print('Guess something bigger!')
        elif rand_num < guess_num :
            print('Guess something smaller')

        else:
            print(f'the game is over , and it took you {counter} time to guess it')
            break
```

player_2.py (how to use count from here to main)

```
from random import randint
def player_2():


    rand_num = randint(1,100) # we generating a random int 1, 100

    count= 0
    while True:
        guess_num = int(input('Guess a number b/w 1 to 100'))
        count += 1
        if rand_num > guess_num:
            print('Guess something bigger!')
        elif rand_num < guess_num :
            print('Guess something smaller')
        else:
            print(f'the game is over , and it took you {count} time to guess it')
            break # is a keyword to break out of anyloop when you needed
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the `return` statement?

Comment: Globals are evil.  You should be  passing each function the values it needs to operate, and have them return the results of their operations.  I'll try to do an example.

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you post a simple example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's a suggested replacement.  Your `player_1` and `player_2` functions are identical.  There's no reason to have them be two functions.  Just have that function return the number of guesses.

Similarly, `turn` can just return the answer it gets.  No need for globals.  Globals are evil, because you can't control who is messing with them.  A single variable should only be visible to the minimum amount of code necessary to do its job.

This code eliminates the globals and handles things in a more general way.

main.py:

```
from random import randint
from player_1 import player_1


def turn():
    rand = randint(1, 2)
    player_turn = int(input("enter number 1 or 2: "))
    if rand == player_turn:
        print("player 1 won the toss")
        return 1
    else:
        print("player 2 won the toss")
        return 2

def play_game( starter ):
    first = starter
    second = 3-starter
    print( f"Player {first}" )
    tries1 = player_1()
    print( f"Player {second}" )
    tries2 = player_1()

    if tries1 < tries2:
        print(f"player {first} won")
    else:
        print(f"player {second} won")

player = turn()
play_game( player )
```

player_1.py

```
from random import randint
def player_1():
    rand_num = randint(1,100) # we generating a random int 1, 100

    counter = 0
    while True:
        guess_num = int(input('Guess a number b/w 1 to 100: '))
        counter += 1
        if rand_num > guess_num:
            print('Guess something bigger!')
        elif rand_num < guess_num :
            print('Guess something smaller')

        else:
            print(f'Your game is over, and it took you {counter} times to guess it')
            return counter
```

Comment: what does second = 3-starter do

Comment: Come on, you can do the math.  If `starter` is 1, second will be 2.  If `starter` is 2, second will be 1.  That just gives you "the other player".